# Android layout not behaving as expected

Tags: android, layout

I'm using Android Studio to try and design a view with a GridLayout at the, a GridView in the middle and a Button at the bottom.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/deliveryType"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radWaitingOption"
                style="@style/caption"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/waiting" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radCollectionOption"
                style="@style/caption"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/collection" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radDeliveryOption"
                style="@style/caption"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/delivery" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/customerDetails"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin">

            <TextView
                style="@style/caption"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_columnWeight=".1"
                android:text="@string/name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/customerName"
                style="@style/text"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight=".5"
                android:text="@string/name" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/caption"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_columnWeight=".1"
                android:text="@string/address" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/customerAddress"
                style="@style/text"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight=".5"
                android:lines="4"
                android:maxLines="4"
                android:text="@string/address" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/caption"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_columnWeight=".1"
                android:text="@string/phone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/customerPhone"
                style="@style/text"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight=".5"
                android:text="@string/phone" />
        </GridLayout>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/deliveryCost"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/customerDetails">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radLocalOption"
                style="@style/caption"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/_2_00" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radNearOption"
                style="@style/caption"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/_2_50" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radFarOption"
                style="@style/caption"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/_3_00" />
        </RadioGroup>

    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/filter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                style="@style/caption"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
                android:text="@string/filter" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtFilter"
                style="@style/text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
                android:hint="@string/filter_customers" />
        </GridLayout>

        <GridView
            style="@style/margin"
            android:id="@+id/customers"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/filter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/addButton"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp">
        </GridView>


        <Button
            style="@style/margin"
            android:id="@+id/addButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In the Android Studio designer it appears as I would expect:

[image: Designer]

but when it shows in the Android emulator, the Gridview appears to be expanded over the bottom of the screen and the button is not showing.

Can any give me pointers to what I have done wrong. Bare in mind this is my first attempt and a Kotlin program, coming from a dotnet background. Layout is so much easier in XAML :)

[image: Emulator]

Answer (score 0):

If you want the LinearLayout, ConstraintLayout and the button to stack up on top of each other, this should do it. It may need a bit of change on your end.
Replace your XML code with this and check:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/deliveryType"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radWaitingOption"
                style="@style/caption"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/waiting" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radCollectionOption"
                style="@style/caption"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/collection" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radDeliveryOption"
                style="@style/caption"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/delivery" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/customerDetails"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin">

            <TextView
                style="@style/caption"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_columnWeight=".1"
                android:text="@string/name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/customerName"
                style="@style/text"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight=".5"
                android:text="@string/name" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/caption"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_columnWeight=".1"
                android:text="@string/address" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/customerAddress"
                style="@style/text"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight=".5"
                android:lines="4"
                android:maxLines="4"
                android:text="@string/address" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/caption"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_columnWeight=".1"
                android:text="@string/phone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/customerPhone"
                style="@style/text"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight=".5"
                android:text="@string/phone" />
        </GridLayout>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/deliveryCost"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/customerDetails">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radLocalOption"
                style="@style/caption"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/_2_00" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radNearOption"
                style="@style/caption"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/_2_50" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radFarOption"
                style="@style/caption"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/_3_00" />
        </RadioGroup>

    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/filter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                style="@style/caption"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
                android:text="@string/filter" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtFilter"
                style="@style/text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
                android:hint="@string/filter_customers" />
        </GridLayout>

        <GridView
            style="@style/margin"
            android:id="@+id/customers"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/filter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/addButton"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp">
        </GridView>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <Button
        style="@style/margin"
        android:id="@+id/addButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```